# Registering Windows Classes Win32

Tags: c, winapi, class, window

what's the best practise for registering window classes for a win32 program?

Do you register every class in the WinMain function or as they're required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to do them as they're required, no need doing it before they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

No Need of registering if you using MFC because this will be doing in the backgrounds.. but  if using win32 you need to register a windows class in WNDCLASS structure if you want to uise a windproc for your custom message handling see the MSDN  link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx

even if you dont give a registerclass the system will be having a class that is registered with the window.

see the [sample](http://www.programminggallery.com/article/vc__/threads___process__messaging__and_memory_handling/general/understanding_the_windows_messaging_and_message_loops)